Is the law of karma completely valid?
We have seen that bad results are caused by bad actions and good results that of good. This is what the law of karma says.If we take the sample of Dhritarashtra , then we see that he was born blind because in one of his past lives he threw fireballs on some birds which made the birds blind. But if we dig deeper then we can also say that the birds were made blind as maybe in some previous lives they have made Dhritarashtra blind due to which the law of karma was implemented through Dhritarashtra on the birds. So why did Dhritarashtra again became blind in the Mahabharata time?
The logic of the law of karma seems a bit flawed to me, as whenever something bad happens to us and we don’t know the reason for it we blame the law of karma but the law of karma itself is creating endless karmas which are repeatedly same in nature . So can anyone explain any other reason why people suffer in this world . Thank you.

I am sorry @Shivadasa but I did not get what you said. Would you please give a simple example. Thank you.
